# how to add dynamic array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this static array here

```
const myQuestions = [
{
  question: "Who is the strongest?",
  answers: {
    a: "Superman",
    b: "The Terminator",
    c: "Waluigi, obviously"
  },
  correctAnswer: "c"
},
{
  question: "What is the best site ever created?",
  answers: {
    a: "SitePoint",
    b: "Simple Steps Code",
    c: "Trick question; they're both the best"
  },
  correctAnswer: "c"
},
{
  question: "Where is Waldo really?",
  answers: {
    a: "Antarctica",
    b: "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
    c: "Sitting in a tree",
    d: "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
  },
  correctAnswer: "d"
}
 ];
```

which contains some questions and the possible answers besides the correct answer
what I want to do is to make this array as a dynamic array 
Which means I'm going to get the information from firebase and push it into this array
can i have some help please because I have no idea how to deal with such kind of arrays

Comment: depends on how you've stored the information in your db

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://itnext.io/how-to-crud-in-angular-firebase-firestore-456353d7c62

Comment: You can use myQuestions.push(child). Actually arrays in js are dynamic not static, you can learn about js arrays here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Using const you can manipulate the array but not reassign the variable. Your array needs some reference an id. I guess the question itself would suffice in order to map the answers to.

Comment: I guess you can first get rid of `const` and change it into `let`, this way you can push into the array. Next, fetch data from the database and push it into your array. Morever, your objects in the array should contain a key? I think? But maybe you don't need to look for specific question but it is a good a thing to always have a unique key or id.